# Secure way to pass data after form submission?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm writing a small app that gets information from the server, allows the user to manipulate it, then saves it back to the server.  When getting the information from the server, the server also gives a password.  When the information gets sent back to the server, the server looks for the password, as a safety precaution.

My question is,  what is a safe way to pass the password after the form submits?  I considered hidden fields, but that would make it possible to find the password.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store it in a session with a specific field defining of password and destroying after made in use.

This is much better usage.

Comment: I'd add a reversible encryption to this method too, but it seems the least likely to be compromised. You could also check the sessionID and userID as added security to ensure nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

You could give the password to Javascript/jQuery and then intercept the normal form submit, append the password to the post data, and then resubmit the form, but that may be a bit overkill...

As long as the password isn't being used for anything else (as in it's randomly generated) and it's single use, putting it in a hidden field shouldn't be much of an issue. Average users don't know how to view hidden fields. However, if you are connecting over HTTP and not HTTPS, your average hacker would be able to view the password coming over the unencrypted network and potentially use it before your user can.

Comment: Assuming the knowledge of your users is absolutely brutal security tactics.